# Execução de tempo em tempo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Como eu faço no universal app win 10 para realizar uma execução de um código de 10 em 10 seg. No form usaria adicionando um time. Por favor me ajudem.

Comment: Faz um while true com algo tipo o thread sleep.

Comment: Como eu faço para usar a  thread sleep?

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000).Wait()

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641223/thread-sleep-replacement-in-net-for-windows-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger(10, false);

TimeTrigger ^ trigger = ref new TimeTrigger(10, false);
```

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-

Comment: Mas onde entra o codigo que sera executado no tempo?

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas possibilidades:

`ThreadPoolTimer`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ThreadPoolTimer timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(async (t) =>
    {
        // do some work not connected with UI
        Debug.WriteLine($"executado: {DateTime.Now}");
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // do some work on UI here;
            //MyTextBlock.Text = "Test";
        });
    }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

---

Outra possibilidade `DispatcherTimer` (esse tem a vantagem de atualizar `UI` diretamente no método delegado)

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mytimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0);
    _mytimer.Tick += Mytimer_Tick;
    _mytimer.Start();
}

private void Mytimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"executado: {DateTime.Now}");
    // do some work on UI here;
    //MyTextBlock.Text = "Test";
}
```

---

Outra possibilidade é utilizar um *Trigger* (gatilho) executado em segundo plano de minutos em minutos.

Sim, minutos, um *Trigger* do tipo `Timer` só pode ser definida a partir de `15 minutos` (caso tente definir valor menor que 15 ocorrerá erro), ou seja, a cada 15 minutos sua `Trigger/Timer` é disparado. O tempo inicial não é baseado no momento em que a *Trigger* e sim a cada 15 minutos "cheios", por exemplo, 00:15, 00:30, ...

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterTask();
    }

    private void RegisterTask()
    {
        //create a task/timer to run each 15 minutes (minimum allowed 15min)
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
        {
            Name = "My Background TimerTrigger"
        };
        builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
        builder.Register();
        Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterTask {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}

sealed partial class App 
{
    protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Can be fired more than once per trigger, check it out.
        Debug.WriteLine($"OnBackgroundActivated - {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

**Código Fonte:**

https://github.com/rubgithub/Timer-UWP

**Referencias:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/BackgroundActivation/cs/SampleConfiguration.cs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271100/timer-in-uwp-app-which-isnt-linked-to-the-ui